grpc throws: Got goaway [11] err=UNAVAILABLE:GOAWAY received; Error code: 11; Debug Text: ping_timeout
I have a grpc client/server solution based on python gRPC version v1.65.4.
After things being stable over quite some time, all of the sudden the client is flooding with this message:
I0000 00:00:1730133857.526170 31218669 chttp2_transport.cc:1182] ipv4:xx.xx.xx.xx:24009: Got goaway [11] err=UNAVAILABLE:GOAWAY received; Error code: 11; Debug Text: ping_timeout {grpc_status:14, http2_error:11, created_time:"2024-10-28T17:44:17.526168+01:00"}

Any idea how to fix this?

This looks like there could be something in the server code that is causing it, and probably not an issue with gRPC itself. Can you share your client and server code to reproduce this, and if you wish to provide more details you may also open an issue on the official repo open issue grpc
